# HP Laptop slow keyboard and mouse response

Tags: windows-10, ssd

I am working on an HP 15-f009wm laptop that I have increased RAM (now it has 8GB) and changed the HDD to an 128GB SSD Disk.

Despite all of this, I get some kind of delayed response whenever I move the pointer or pressing any keys. It is really annoying and it doesn't let the people use the laptop.

The processor is an AMD E1-2100, RAM 8GB DDR3 and the SSD disk is Kingston SA400S37º10G 128GB.

I will format the disk completely so I can install Windows 10 from scratch. But I defragged it using Medicat USB - Auslogics Disk Defrag Professional and it shows me the following:

- Performance: 98.50% > 98.51%
- Fragmentation: 5.59% > 5.59% (Parameter is in poor condition and requires attention)
- Free Space Fragmentation: 7.49% > 7.43% (Parameter is in poor condition and requires attention)
- Fragmented: 218 folders > 205 folders (Parameter is in poor condition and requires attention)

So, I am not sure if take the SSD disk to warranty or just format the disk. I have tried to restore Windows 10 and it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't defrag SSDs. It doesn't help their speed in the slightest & will cause early wear-out.

Comment: When you made these changes, did you update BIOS and all drivers (especially chipset, power and mouse)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defragmentating SSDs is not recommended as they are not structured as HDD. I would recommend to reinstall drivers for peripherals from the official HP website, if this does not help try reinstalling the HDD and see if the issue persists to discard any hardware issue.